# Requesting data from website that is using cloudflare PHP file gets content

Tags: php, cloudflare

I'm trying to read a website with file_gets_content but it isnt working because they are using cloudflare.

My code

```
 <?php
$habbo = $_GET['name'];

$home = file_get_contents("http://www.drabbo.nl/home/".$habbo);
if (eregi("http://www.drabbo.nl/drabboweb/63_1d5d8853040f30be0cc82355679bba7c3395/web-gallery/images/mydrabbo/profile/drabbo_online_anim.gif", $home)){
$img = "img link";
}else{
$img = "img link";
}
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$im = imagecreatefromgif($img);
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

How can I still do it

Comment: You probably can't. There is a reason the Webmaster pays for cloud flare ;)

Comment: You dont need to pay for cloudflare,